# How to continue giving list number after insert a block of code

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, list

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)

Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ e:/emacs/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/org/)

In my org file,

```
1. one thing
   #+begin_src sh
   ls -la
   #+end_src
2. second thing
```

But when I export html, it shows:

> 1. one thing
>
>    ls -la
>
> 1 second thing

This happens when I use Yasnippet, some lines can't be indent. 
For example,

```
#+begin_src dot :file xx :cmdline -Tpdf :exports none :results silent
 sss
#+end_src 
[[file:xx]]
```

The `[[file:xx]]` can't forcely indent.

**Update-2015-12-9**
[image]

Comment: Your exports as expected for me, what are your emacs and org versions?

Comment: @biondo 
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 
Org-mode version 8.2.10

Comment: Does work as expected for me with the same versions (emacs 24.5.1, org-mode 8.2.10).  Does your file contain **exactly** that?

Comment: @JeanPierre I repeat my procedure.  And I find the reason is that I copy the text `#+begin_src sh
   ls -la
   #+end_src`. So it interrupt the number list. I success only whey I manually type this code. So it obviously different in the format.  Then when I encounter the problem that   the number list was interrupted. How can I recover that number list?

Comment: Make sure you indent the lines between the numbered ones.

Comment: @JeanPierre. Indent lines works well. But when I use Yasnippet, some lines can't be indent.  For example, `      #+begin_src dot :file xx :cmdline -Tzzz :exports none :results silent
            sss
      #+end_src

   [[file:xx]]
`  The `[[file:xx]]` can't forcely indent.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the information of this last comment?

Comment: In my experience `#+begin_src` must be indented correctly. `#+end_src` is aligned accordingly to  `#+begin_src`. The indentation of the source code does not matter. It may be that at copy-paste `#+begin_src` ends up at a wrong indentation. If that happens you need to correct it manually.

Comment: @Tobias You say correct it manually, is it just to use `Tab` or any way else. Since I press tab. It didn't work.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. The most remarkable effect in org 8.2.10 is that `#+end_src` does not have the same indentation level as `#+begin_src`. Note, you do not have the [document structure](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Document-structure) specified in the org-manual. At the beginning of your document you need at least one heading starting with a star `*` as first character of the header line followed by a space and some header text. When I add such a heading the `#+end_src` problem disappears. To have `[[file:xx]]` tab-indented correctly, you need at least 1 leading space.

Comment: @Tobias I do as you say, and I can continue adding consecutive number by entering M-return before `[[file:xx]]`. But after `[[file:xx]]` I can't continue the number. I update the question with a picture. Thank you very much

Comment: I just ran into this same problem, and the results line must be indented as well.

Comment: @user2699 See my answer. (Note: Without this comment user2699 would not be notified.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an `org-mode`-bug.

The problem is that the case of "Lists" is handled before "Special blocks" in `org-indent-line`.

If you exchange these cases the tab-indentation behaves better.

The corrected code for `org-indent-line` in `org-mode` 8.2.10 is:

```el
(require 'org)
(if (equal (mapcar 'string-to-number (split-string org-version "\\.")) '(8 2 10))
    (defun org-indent-line ()
      "Indent line depending on context."
      (interactive)
      (let* ((pos (point))
         (itemp (org-at-item-p))
         (case-fold-search t)
         (org-drawer-regexp (or org-drawer-regexp "\000"))
         (inline-task-p (and (featurep 'org-inlinetask)
                 (org-inlinetask-in-task-p)))
         (inline-re (and inline-task-p
                 (org-inlinetask-outline-regexp)))
         column)
    (if (and orgstruct-is-++ (eq pos (point)))
        (let ((indent-line-function (cadadr (assoc 'indent-line-function org-fb-vars))))
          (indent-according-to-mode))
      (beginning-of-line 1)
      (cond
       ;; Headings
       ((looking-at org-outline-regexp) (setq column 0))
       ;; Footnote definition
       ((looking-at org-footnote-definition-re) (setq column 0))
       ;; Literal examples
       ((looking-at "[ \t]*:\\( \\|$\\)")
        (setq column (org-get-indentation))) ; do nothing
       ;; Drawers
       ((and (looking-at "[ \t]*:END:")
         (save-excursion (re-search-backward org-drawer-regexp nil t)))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (1- (match-beginning 1)))
          (setq column (current-column))))
       ;; Special blocks
       ((and (looking-at "[ \t]*#\\+end_\\([a-z]+\\)")
         (save-excursion
           (re-search-backward
            (concat "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_" (downcase (match-string 1))) nil t)))
        (setq column (org-get-indentation (match-string 0))))
       ((and (not (looking-at "[ \t]*#\\+begin_"))
         (org-between-regexps-p "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_" "[ \t]*#\\+end_"))
        (save-excursion
          (re-search-backward "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_\\([a-z]+\\)" nil t))
        (setq column
          (cond ((equal (downcase (match-string 1)) "src")
             ;; src blocks: let `org-edit-src-exit' handle them
             (org-get-indentation))
            ((equal (downcase (match-string 1)) "example")
             (max (org-get-indentation)
                  (org-get-indentation (match-string 0))))
            (t
             (org-get-indentation (match-string 0))))))
       ;; Lists
       ((ignore-errors (goto-char (org-in-item-p)))
        (setq column (if itemp
                 (org-get-indentation)
               (org-list-item-body-column (point))))
        (goto-char pos))
       ;; This line has nothing special, look at the previous relevant
       ;; line to compute indentation
       (t
        (beginning-of-line 0)
        (while (and (not (bobp))
            (not (looking-at org-table-line-regexp))
            (not (looking-at org-drawer-regexp))
            ;; When point started in an inline task, do not move
            ;; above task starting line.
            (not (and inline-task-p (looking-at inline-re)))
            ;; Skip drawers, blocks, empty lines, verbatim,
            ;; comments, tables, footnotes definitions, lists,
            ;; inline tasks.
            (or (and (looking-at "[ \t]*:END:")
                 (re-search-backward org-drawer-regexp nil t))
                (and (looking-at "[ \t]*#\\+end_")
                 (re-search-backward "[ \t]*#\\+begin_"nil t))
                (looking-at "[ \t]*[\n:#|]")
                (looking-at org-footnote-definition-re)
                (and (not inline-task-p)
                 (featurep 'org-inlinetask)
                 (org-inlinetask-in-task-p)
                 (or (org-inlinetask-goto-beginning) t))))
          (beginning-of-line 0))
        (cond
         ;; There was a list item above.
         ((ignore-errors (goto-char (org-in-item-p)))
          (goto-char (org-list-get-top-point (org-list-struct)))
          (setq column (org-get-indentation)))
         ;; There was an heading above.
         ((looking-at "\\*+[ \t]+")
          (if (not org-adapt-indentation)
          (setq column 0)
        (goto-char (match-end 0))
        (setq column (current-column))))
         ;; A drawer had started and is unfinished
         ((looking-at org-drawer-regexp)
          (goto-char (1- (match-beginning 1)))
          (setq column (current-column)))
         ;; Else, nothing noticeable found: get indentation and go on.
         (t (setq column (org-get-indentation))))))
      ;; Now apply indentation and move cursor accordingly
      (goto-char pos)
      (if (<= (current-column) (current-indentation))
          (org-indent-line-to column)
        (save-excursion (org-indent-line-to column)))
      ;; Special polishing for properties, see `org-property-format'
      (setq column (current-column))
      (beginning-of-line 1)
      (if (looking-at org-property-re)
          (replace-match (concat (match-string 4)
                     (format org-property-format
                         (match-string 1) (match-string 3)))
                 t t))
      (org-move-to-column column))))
  (error "Bugfix of `org-indent-line' is for org-version 8.2.10 only."))
```

Note, this source code is not tested thoroughly because of lack of time.

If this is not corrected in higher org-mode versions one should issue a bug-report.

Remark on your Update-2015-12-9: With this fix you still need to add a space in front of `[[file:xx]]` to get it indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[@num]` syntax described in [Plain lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Plain-lists.html). Below is an example on how to use it according to your needs.

```
1. first thing
2. second thing

#+BEGIN_SRC python
print("Insert a block of code")
#+END_SRC

3. [@3] third thing

[[file:file][file]]

10. [@4] fourth thing

5. fifth thing
```

As you can see, after renumbering the list, what matters is that the number after @.